# Display full-width layer under a li item inside a navigation menu using css html

Tags: html, css, navigation

So far so good to setup a basic navigation menu with 4 items, let's say Home - Products - Blog - About.

But how can you get a full width layer displayed under the product menu item using only css/ html - no bootstrap or whatsoever? Width: 100% doesnt help. It automaticly resize to the width of the menu item above, the product item...

Answer (score 0):

if i am right you trying to do something like that,
this is the link to the wc3 templates:

https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/tryit.asp?filename=tryw3css_templates_photo2&stacked=h

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>W3.CSS Template</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<style>
body,h1 {font-family: "Raleway", Arial, sans-serif}
h1 {letter-spacing: 6px}
.w3-row-padding img {margin-bottom: 12px}
</style>
<body>

<!-- !PAGE CONTENT! -->
<div class="w3-content" style="max-width:1500px">

<!-- Header -->
<header class="w3-panel w3-center w3-opacity" style="padding:128px 16px">
  <h1 class="w3-xlarge">PHOTOGRAPHER</h1>
  <h1>John Doe</h1>

  <div class="w3-padding-32">
    <div class="w3-bar w3-border">
      <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Home</a>
      <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-light-grey">Portfolio</a>
      <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Contact</a>
      <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-hide-small">Weddings</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>

<!-- Photo Grid -->
<div class="w3-row-padding w3-grayscale" style="margin-bottom:128px">
  <div class="w3-half">
    <img src="/w3images/wedding.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <img src="/w3images/rocks.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <img src="/w3images/falls2.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <img src="/w3images/paris.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <img src="/w3images/nature.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <img src="/w3images/mist.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <img src="/w3images/paris.jpg" style="width:100%">
  </div>

  <div class="w3-half">
    <img src="/w3images/underwater.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <img src="/w3images/ocean.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <img src="/w3images/wedding.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <img src="/w3images/mountainskies.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <img src="/w3images/rocks.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <img src="/w3images/underwater.jpg" style="width:100%">
  </div>
</div>

<!-- End Page Content -->
</div>

<!-- Footer -->
<footer class="w3-container w3-padding-64 w3-light-grey w3-center w3-large"> 
  <i class="fa fa-facebook-official w3-hover-opacity"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-instagram w3-hover-opacity"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-snapchat w3-hover-opacity"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-pinterest-p w3-hover-opacity"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-twitter w3-hover-opacity"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-linkedin w3-hover-opacity"></i>
  <p>Powered by <a href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/default.asp" target="_blank" class="w3-hover-text-green">w3.css</a></p>
</footer>

</body>
</html>
```

I believe you adding blocks (divs) not correctly, this is the reason why it is resizing, please check this code below i believe it will explain that you can use fixed side with px, etc. hope i understand your question.

Comment: Hi Cursedmonk, I'm trying to achieve a menu kind of like on this link : https://www.foodnhotelasia.com/ . I guess, indeed, the question is where to place the div's in the menu. Right now I put them after the "ul" of the parent layer. For instance nav > ul > div > li thx, Jon